# Xcode/iOS5: Move UIView up, when keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, ios5

I'd like to move up my view, when the keyboard is shown. The keyboard (height: 216) should push up my view with it's height. Is this possible with a simple code?

Comment: There is no need to alter your title to include SOLVED, the accepted answer shows this.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To move the view `up`, just change its `center`. First, keep the original one in a `CGPoint` property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    ...
    self.originalCenter = self.view.center;
    ...
}
```

Then, change as needed when keyboard shows up:

```
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.originalCenter.x, /* new calculated y */);
```

Finally, restore it when keyboard is hidden:

```
self.view.center = self.originalCenter;
```

Add animation sugar as you wish

You have more than one way to know when the keyboard appears.

Observing **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification** notification.

```
/* register notification in any of your initWithNibName:bundle:, viewDidLoad, awakeFromNib, etc. */
{
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];     
    ...
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    /* move your views here */
}
```

Do the opposite with `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`.

-OR-

Implement **UITextFieldDelegate**

Detect when editing begin/end to move views around.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    /* keyboard is visible, move views */
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    /* resign first responder, hide keyboard, move views */
}
```

Depending on the actual text fields you may need to track in which field is the user editing, add a timer to avoid moving views too much.

Comment: Thank you madmw, this is perfect :)

Comment: @AlexisW did you change your mind to accept a less complete answer *six months* later or there is a glitch in SO? Weird.

Comment: it was not my intention to lower your reputation or even to disregard your detailed answer. Since I am here on stack I learned pretty much about programming. So when I need a function, I just search for it to learn. I also learned that sometimes simple answers or examples are more helpful to realise for "newbies". Thank you anyway for your help madmw.

Comment: I don't care very much about SO reputation, just trying to understand  why did you pick an incorrect (IMHO of course) answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I just attempted to use this solution for a similar problem. There's one issue with this solution: you should set your originalCenter parameter in viewDidAppear rather than viewDidLoad. This is because UI elements have not been placed in their locations at this point in the cycle, but have been by viewDidAppear. originalCenter in viewDidLoad was giving me x=0, y=0.

Comment: what should y b? how do I calculate this minus the keyboard

Comment: This works fine. only caveat is that equal amount of portion gets hidden on top. How should I cover up for the lost area at the top?

Answer (score 31):

do like this.
after keyboard visible use this code

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-10,320,480);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Changing the frame did some warping though, so I changed the center of self.view instead, and the animation smoothly moved the view with the keyboard :)

Answer (score 13):

I did this in a similar fashion to djromero except that I adjusted the frame origin of the view rather than its centre.

The view that i'm moving is a UIScrollView, and I want it to move relative to a UITextField element, so that the text field always shows. The position of this text field can vary depending on the offset of the scroll view.

So my code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    });
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)getKeyBoardHeight:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
    NSInteger keyboardHeight = keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;
    return keyboardHeight;
}

-(void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSInteger keyboardHeight;
    keyboardHeight = [self getKeyBoardHeight:notification];
    NSInteger scrollViewFrameHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
    NSInteger textFieldRelativePosition = self.tableView.frame.origin.y - self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSInteger textFieldFrameOffset = scrollViewFrameHeight - textFieldRelativePosition;
    NSInteger movement = MAX(0,keyboardHeight-textFieldFrameOffset); // Offset from where the keyboard will appear.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-movement,
                                           self.scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                           self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    });
}
```

The view controller is a UITextFieldDelegate and also subscribes to UIKeyboardDidShowNotification so that we are able to access the size of the keyboard.

When the keyboard shows, we calculate the relative offset of the UITextField (adjusted for scroll offset) and the keyboard and them change the origin of the UIScrollView so that it moves just enough for the UITextField still to be showing.

If the UITextField will still show even if the keyboard appears, then the origin does not change.

Comment: Your method of pushing the view worked whereas moving the center didn't work. (Moving the center pushed up, but when I moved it back, it pushed down too far).

Answer (score 13):

This is the most easiest and efficient way to achieve this:

Add the following constants:

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;
```

Add this to your view controller:

```
CGFloat animatedDistance;
```

And add these methods to your code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
CGRect textFieldRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator =
midline - viewRect.origin.y
- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator =
(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
* viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
if (heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
else
{
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textfield{

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Worked great for me thank you, I just dropped it in, set my UITextField delegates and it did the rest. Thanks!

Comment: works perfect, one suggestion though, use block based animation instead begin/commitAnimation ...

Comment: Perfect! And its really easy and quick to integrate in your existing code.

Comment: I agree. This is THE BEST and NEATEST solution on the planet. I don't even have to think about anything else, and it even integrates nicely with my textFieldShouldReturn (set a chain of the next of becomeFirstResponder using tag). Your solution still works even after 2 years from your original date of post. Thank you!

Comment: It makes a black area when keyboard is already hidden, but the view still animates.

Answer (score 5):

mark, apple document:
[Managing the keyboard - Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have some code calling `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];`. You should move your view just after this call.

Comment: `myView.center = //whatever your center was before + (CGPointMake(0, 216))`

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGFloat y = textField.frame.origin.y;
    if (y >= 350) //not 380
   {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 320 - textField.frame.origin.y;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{self.view.frame = frame;}];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect returnframe =self.view.frame;
returnframe.origin.y = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{self.view.frame = frame;}];
}
```

just edit these two methods.
simple answer to all d codes. In the if statement change the value according to the iphone i.e., if iphone 4S change it to 265 and in didbeginediting change the 320 to 240 and if iphone 5 change it to 350 and in didbeginediting method keep it as 320, because it is the logic if u understand

Comment: pls guys help me solving this if anybody knows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670934/adding-calendar-and-using-each-date-as-a-button?noredirect=1#comment36369604_23670934

Answer (score 0):

This is Tendulkar solution, but keeping in mind original frame size and removing keyboard. This solution works for all devices.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
return YES;
 }


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-50,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Do not forget set UITextField delegate!

Answer (score 0):

[Sample project Based on](https://github.com/LuAndreCast/iOS_Projects/blob/master/%5BObjective-C%5D%20scrollView/scrollviews/scrollviews/uiviewOneViewController.m)  Apple Reference  [Keyboard Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

**H File:   (Don't Forget the *UITextFieldDelegate*)**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;


    //items on view
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *partySwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *partyLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *partyNameTextfield;
```

**M file:**

```
    //MARK: View Loading
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}//eom

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}//eom

    //MARK: textfield delegates
-(bool)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return true;
}//eom

    //MARK: - Keyboard Observers
    // Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}


- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info      = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize           = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect        = myView.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;

    [myView.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, myView.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}//eom

    // Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets          = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollview.contentInset             = contentInsets;
    scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets    = contentInsets;
}//eom
```