# Move the UIView when keyboard appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm sorry about my English language.

I tried to find before it acts. But the problem is that `ViewController` in the landscape and created `UIView` half of the `ViewController`. In `UIView` have `UITextView`.  But now when keyboard appear background in the `ViewController` scroll down below the keyboard. And see just `UIView`. If touch space, keyboard will disappear and background comeback. I want to just is move the `UIView` when keyboard appear.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    NSValue *aValue = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];

    [aValue getValue:&keyboardBounds];
    keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
    if (!keyboardIsShowing)
    {
        keyboardIsShowing = YES;
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.size.height -= 168;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    NSValue *aValue = [note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    [aValue getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
    if (keyboardIsShowing)
    {
        keyboardIsShowing = NO;
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.size.height += 168;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the super call in your 'viewDidAppear'.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears) looks like it might be what you're looking for.

In short:

1. Detect when the keyboard appears with **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification**.
2. The [user info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keyboard_Notification_User_Info_Keys) for that notification describes the frame of the keyboard.
3. Adjust the frame(s) of your view(s) to get them out from under the keyboard.