# How to move up a modal UIView inside of a UIViewcontroller (StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

i've got a UIView, dragged of Object Library, inside of a UIViewcontroller created by StoryBoard.

Inside of this UIView, I put two Text Field to grab user name and password, and one button to log in.

How can I move only this View when the keyboard appears? I'm able to move the whole View Controller, but i can't find a solution to move only the View.

I just dragged one View of the Object Library, inside my Viewcontroller and created one Outlet in .h Viecontroller - @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView; and connected do this View, i'm in doubt too if I need to do something more to add the view to the project.

Thanks in advance!!

[View inside UIViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W12fw.png);

Comment: Not sure if I should mark as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282449/move-uiview-up-when-the-keyboard-appears-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe for 
`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. Then move modal view up when keyboard appears, down when keyboard hides.

Then animate modal view up or down whether keyboard will show or hide:

Move up:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
    CGRect currentFrame = modalView.frame;
    currentFrame.origin.y -= VIEW_FRAME_OFFSET;
    modalView.frame = currentFrame;
}];
```

Move down:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
    CGRect currentFrame = modalView.frame;
    currentFrame.origin.y += VIEW_FRAME_OFFSET;
    modalView.frame = currentFrame;
}];
```

Also if you want you can use other keyboard notifications listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardWillShowNotification).

Comment: The Uiview only moves quickly after implement this code and returns to the same point, beneath the keyboard. Any ideia?

Thanks!