# No touch event working when keyboard appears (only when view is animated)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikeyboard

I have added functionality when keyboard appears we will up cause keyboard hides most part of ipad, but when view is up no touch event works, main motive to dismiss keyboards when tap or touch outside 
below is screenshots shows I can't touch outside I have to use done button

[image: ipad screenshot]

Comment: you should consider editing your question and correcting sentence structure and punctuation!

Comment: Please show your `textFieldDidBegin` delegate

Comment: @SahebRoy here `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if([tfUserName isFirstResponder] ){
        userHover.hidden = false;
        
    }
    
    if([tfPassword isFirstResponder]){
        pwdHover.hidden = false;
        
    }
    
    if([tfURL isFirstResponder]){
        urlHover.hidden = false;
        [self animateTextView:YES];
    }

    
}
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move UIView up when the keyboard appears in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282449/move-uiview-up-when-the-keyboard-appears-in-ios)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a `UITapGestureRecognizer`!

First of all define a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your header (.h) file.

Then in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
tapGesture =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(closeKeyBoard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Now the method which closes the keyboard:

```
-(void)closeKeyBoard {

[self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

That's all you need!

Cheers

Comment: already tried similar method , not working also applied your code

Comment: @iDeepak Try NSlog in the method! Will it be called at least?

Comment: Add    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; to your viewDidLoad!!