# Move the UIView with some UITextFields up when we edit UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I have one UIView. Inside that I have two text fields - `username` and `password`, and one `submit` UIButton. I kept my UIView at centre of screen. So now when I edit my `username and password field`, my password field is getting hide by keyboard.

So is it possible to show my "total UIView with that two text fields" up, when my keyboard is on?

Please help on some code.Thanks!

updated code:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, (self.scrollView.contentSize.height + 260));
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,120);
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
```

Comment: This has already been answered <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282449/move-uiview-up-when-the-keyboard-appears-in-ios>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `UIView` to `UIScrollView`. Then in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method add keyboard height (normally 260) to your scrollview's `contentSize` and change the `contentOffset` accordingly. Don't forget to reset the `contentSize` and `contentOffset` back to normal values in `textFieldDidEndEditing`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, (self.scrollView.contentSize.height + 260));
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, <desired height>);
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
     self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
```

Comment: i will chnage the uiview to uiscroll view. Then can you explain me that key board code and that chnage the contentoffset coding

Comment: your code is getting some name error for `desired` `loginRegisterView` `SCREEN_WIDTH , SCREEN_HEIGHT`

Comment: i just changed my uiview to uiscroll view

Comment: By desired height what I meant is the height which you want :D

Comment: height is for scrollview or for keyboard?

Comment: Set the contentOffset which you want something like self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100);

Comment: i did, I just changed my uiview to uiscroll view.Now i add your code.But its same like looking. My scroll view is not moving up and also keyboard is not reducing height

Comment: Try increasing the content size. Actually size of keyboard won't decrease. This will make your scroll view scrollable so that you can see the field below keyboard by scrolling

Comment: content size?/There is no x,y, w , h declared in your solution to change the content size?

Comment: self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, (self.scrollView.contentSize.height + 260));
Increase 260 and check