# How to keep multiple TextViews from being hidden by keyboard AND top of screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app has a view controller with eight TextView boxes. I have them all in a content view, inside of a ScrollView. I've adjusted the content and scroll height so I can scroll through and see all of the TextViews, but when the keyboard comes up, it covers the bottom TextView and I can't scroll far enough for that TextView to actually be visible.

All the solutions I've tried have only partially worked. Currently I have [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282535/7667634) in my code, and it does allow the bottom TextView to be visible, but now the top two can't be reached when I scroll with the keyboard open.

Most other solutions are for TextFields (like [this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard--mobile-6103)), which I have tried by essentially replacing all the TextField references with TextView, but that doesn't work.

The only thing I can actually get to work is if I drastically increase the content height to allow for scrolling further. But I don't want a bunch of empty space at the bottom of the screen.

How can I make sure all TextViews can be scrolled to with the keyboard open?

Comment: I personally use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding - set your ScrollView's class to the provided one and it handles the rest.

Comment: But would I be able to use something like that if I plan to submit my app to the App Store? I've read that Apple's guidelines are strict, so I've been trying to do all the coding myself without relying on drop-in solutions that I don't personally own the rights to.

Comment: That won't be a problem at all. Almost every piece of software is going to have dependencies of some sort, you just have to read the licenses of any item you include.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below solution

```
      #define k_KEYBOARD_OFFSET 95.0

    -(void)keyboardWillAppear {
        // Move current view up / down with Animation
        if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self moveViewUp:NO];
        }
        else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
        {
            [self moveViewUp:YES];
        }
    }

    -(void)keyboardWillDisappear {
        if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self moveViewUp:YES];
        }
        else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
        {
            [self moveViewUp:NO];
        }
    }

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView1 {
    {
            //move the main view up, so the keyboard will not hide it.
            if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
            {
                [self moveViewUp:YES];
            }
    }

    //Custom method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is appeared / disappeared
    -(void)moveViewUp:(BOOL)bMovedUp
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4]; // to slide the view up

        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        if (bMovedUp) {
            // 1. move the origin of view up so that the text field will come above the keyboard
            rect.origin.y -= k_KEYBOARD_OFFSET;

            // 2. increase the height of the view to cover up the area behind the keyboard
            rect.size.height += k_KEYBOARD_OFFSET;
        } else {
            // revert to normal state of the view.
            rect.origin.y += k_KEYBOARD_OFFSET;
            rect.size.height -= k_KEYBOARD_OFFSET;
        }

        self.view.frame = rect;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        // register keyboard notifications to appear / disappear the keyboard
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillDisappear)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        // unregister for keyboard notifications while moving to the other screen.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                      object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                      object:nil];
    }
```