# How to move text up in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have added a UITextView in my view which coves more than 80% of my whole view. When I click on text view and started editing on it, after few lines text are hidden under keyboard, How can I scroll automatically up once text touches keyboard.

[image]

TIA

Comment: Good question but if you had searched stack overflow, you would have found plenty of answers

Comment: please take little more effort and search :(

Comment: tried reading the docs of `[textView setFrame:]`?

Comment: For a starting point ... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears

Comment: @tGilani It looks like Feroz likes your solution. I'd suggest posting it as an answer so he can accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these methods given below...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:self.view.window]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

Also check google you will get the solution further easily.

Comment: I think @Feroz don't want to hide keyboard..!! He just want to move text up!!

Comment: @NSS U are right I want to move text up. From tGilani's link, there they are rearranging the view's height or width itself. Is this the solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

refer this below link are you using textview .just simply use textview instead of textfield .
and follow the below [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LbLrsGKSkY).