# Push view up when keyboard shown

Tags: ios

I need to push the entire up (it has scrollview) when keyboard shown
but can't seem to get it working with this code.
All the code being hit but it just doesn't push up the view.
I am following the example here.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

```
    - (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeField = nil;
}
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: could you edit your question to show a screenshot of your XIB / storyboard file, showing how your view is laid out and the hierarchy of it (i.e. the view controller, the scroll view, the subviews inside that scrollview, etc.)?  I suspect you don't have anything *inside* your scrollview, but instead the scrollview is a peer and on the same level as all the other subviews.

Comment: Possible dup? check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears)

Comment: It is all dynamically.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I searched everywhere seems like nobody could solve this one.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that the keyboard appears when the user clicks on a textfield right? 
you have to use the method of the delegate for the UITextField.

in your viewController.h add UITextFieldDelegate and in your .m insert:

```
   - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
  [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
 }


  - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
 }

 - (void) animateTextField: (UITextField *)textField up: (BOOL) up
{
const int movementDistance = 140; // tweak as needed
const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

[UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

add also these methods:

```
 -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
 [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
 Return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use scrollView in your view. then put all other subviews in the scrollView and then set the content offset of scrollView in "textfieldShouldBeginEditing" method.

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,160)]; // this is just an example
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! Instead I decided to use a tableview. Insert your UITextFields in the TableViewCells and it will scroll up automatically when keyboard comes up!