# TextField hidden by keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a textfield which brings up the keyboard. The keyboard hides the bottom of the text field. I have placed my textField inside a scroll view and I have written the following code in the view.

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Called when the keyboard is shown
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _driverSignupScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _driverSignupScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    CGPoint activeFieldPoint = CGPointMake(_activeField.frame.origin.x, _activeField.frame.origin.y + _activeField.frame.size.height);
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeFieldPoint)) {
        [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:_activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Called when the keyboard is hidden
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

But the control never goes inside my `if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeFieldPoint))` and so it does not scroll up.

The `_activeField` is being set correctly in another method.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: You need to covert the keyboard frame to the locale frame.

Comment: The was supposed to be "convert", not "covert".

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I tried apple's docs as well (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) but it's not working for me either

Comment: @Oren Yes, I have got this working. What I basically did was that I made a table view and inside each cell, I put a UITextField. This will automatically take care of the keyboard scrolling - you will not need to do anything else. If however, you do not want to do this in a table view, you will have to write the code for handling this as in the question (I will post my code later on my blog and post the link here). But I think tableview is the best way to do that with very less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at TPKeyboardAvoiding: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

It makes keyboard management insanely easy. It's how Apple should have designed it to begin with.

Comment: I ended up using this in the beginning. It worked wonderfully. Then I moved my view to a table view layout with textfields in it. If you put the textfields in tableview, the keyboard handling is done automatically. If you are not using tableview, I recommend using this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead put your textField in UIView & try moving up your UIView.

Here is a [sample working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417123/1307844)

Comment: Any reason my code is not working? This code is present on the Apple docs.

Comment: I am not sure but I can give a suggestion that you may need to tweak the line `aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;`

You can try it as , `CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;`

Then `aRect = CGRectMake(aRect.frame.origin.x, aRect.frame.origin.y, aRect.frame.size.width, aRect.frame.size.height-kbSize.height);`