# xcode 5 UITableView always fills entire length of screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I can't figure out how to prevent a `UITableView` from taking up the entire screen. The cell type is dynamic, and I want to have a table view and a text field below it. Here is what my storyboard looks like:

[image: storyboard view]

I've created a custom `UIViewController` (`CustomViewController`)

**Attempt #1**: I already tried changing the height directly:

```
// CustomViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    CGRect frame = [self.tableView frame];
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 40)];
}
```

**Attempt #2**: I thought changing the *view* in Attribute Inspector so that it doesn't Scale to Fit

[image: attribute inspector view]

Here is always what the final outcome looks like:

[image: simulation view]

Notice after the cells I add information (random 1, ..., random 4), there are empty cells below it. Also, not pictured in the screencap is the missing text field because the table view takes up the entire screen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a pin to the TableView. Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to Superview.

Comment: You're probably aware, but just as a reminder, the textfield at the bottom will become covered by the keyboard when it becomes first responder.  Also, I think @CaptJak has the right idea here.

Comment: Not very difficult to handle the keyboard problem:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7953036/2535467

Comment: @CaptJak, I did a pin and it worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you!! :)

Comment: I knew I should've posted an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should add a pin to retain the spacing between the bottom of the TableView.** Go to Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to Superview, for the tableView.

As @danh said, you will also be covering the textField once you touch it because the keyboard will pop up over it. The simplest solution for that is to shift the view once the text field is touched using:

In the header:

```
CGRect *frame;
```

In the implementation:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    /* keyboard is visible, move views */
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
    frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 70;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    /* resign first responder, hide keyboard, move views */
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
    frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 70;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This view is using auto-layout, so setting a frame will have no effects. You need to use constraints to size your table view how you want it to within the view of the parent UIViewController.