# Add textfield and send button like typical chat app

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, chat

I am struggling with something that seems like should be simple but is turning out to not be. I want to add a `UITextField` and send button anchored to the bottom of the screen above my tab bar and below my `UITableview'. I tried a footer, but it just adds to bottom of last row.

I need for it to move up when keyboard is presented.

Comment: Can you give more details of your problem

Comment: Why did i get docked?

Comment: Kevin, i am just trying to add a view to the bottom of my tableview which contains a textfield and button just like a typical chat app. And when i tap inside textfield a keyboard is presented and shoves the view with textfield up to above the keyboard. I have tried adding a footer which doesn't give results i want and i have tried adding a view without luck.

Comment: also i want it anchored to the bottom just like any typical chat app. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears here shows you how to move the whole UIView when the keyboard is presented. I think this what you need

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I think i am still missing something...how to even add the textfield and button and anchor it to the bottom of the screen/tableview. I need to be able to do this first...then push up the whole view when keyboard is presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can insert tableView in custom UIViewController and one more subview with send UITextField at the bottom. Then you follow notifications about keyboard presenting and change tableView and send UITextField frames as you wish. Something like that:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillDisappear:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

#pragma mark - Keyboard appearance/disappearance handling

- (void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    [self.tableView setContentInset:contentInsets];
    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:contentInsets];

    CGRect messageFrame = self.messageTextView.frame;
    messageFrame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height;
    [self.messageTextView setFrame:messageFrame];
}

- (void)keyboardWillDisappear:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    CGRect messageFrame = self.messageTextView.frame;
    messageFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height;
    [self.messageTextView setFrame:messageFrame];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wisors. So it seems this addressees the keyboard handling. In storyboard i have setup the screen up as a UIViewController with a tableview inside it. I shrank the tableview from the bottom and added a view which has the text field and button...however when i run the app...the view, button and textfield all do not show.

Comment: There are a lot of possible ways you did something wrong :) Are you sure that right UIViewController is loaded? Try to log some message in the -viewDidLoad method.

Comment: yes, its definitely loading my view. My tableview is getting populated as i expect. When i shrink my tableview in storyboard, this is also reflected. However, the view i have added below my tableview along with textfield and button do not display.

Comment: Check autoresizing mask for bottom subview in the "Size Inspector" pane and align it to bottom of main view. BTW, is your UIViewController embedded inside UINavigationController?

Comment: ah ok that got me closer! I am making progress now but it seems that when i tapped into textfield...the whole did automatically move up except the send button. I am not sure what happened to it.

Comment: And yes it is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: ok now i added this in the code above for the button:     CGRect messageFrame2 = self.sendButton.frame;
    messageFrame2.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height;
    [self.sendButton setFrame:messageFrame];

Comment: But it is centering the button inside the textfield

Comment: That's why you need the bottom subview container for both UITextField and UIButton inside. You just change one frame instead of handling two. BTW, you'll need to change that container frame (as well as tableView frame) when text would be input and newline happened.

Comment: ok i have button fixed...but the view itself does not slide up.

Comment: You should use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`, as that represents the size of the keyboard *before* the change.

Comment: I also recommend computing the (visible) height as `window.frame.size.height - keyboardRect.origin.y`, as the keyboard is generally simply moved offscreen, not resized. You should also use the computed height (as above) for the content inset in `keyboardWillDisappear` instead of `UIEdgeInsetsZero` to account for custom `inputAccessoryView`s, which may remain visible on-screen even when the keyboard itself is hidden and thus still affect your views.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
var commentField:UITableViewCell!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillDisappear:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){

    var userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    var contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var messageFrame:CGRect = self.commentField.frame
    messageFrame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    self.commentField.frame = messageFrame

}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
    var userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    UIView.commitAnimations()

    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    var messageFrame:CGRect = self.commentField.frame
    messageFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    self.commentField.frame = messageFrame
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why commentField is tableViewCell?

Comment: Not important, just happened to be in my case

Comment: Can u please help me a little bit? I have tableView and uiview with textfield and button. And this view has bottom constraint to tabbar 0. Should I also increase this constraint to make it work? Thanks. I will uparrow, if it helps:)

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember these stuff :(

Comment: Ok;) have a nice day