# Can i update value of label by long press on it - iOS

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uilabel, long-press

I write a simple application with Xcode 5 on iPhone iOS7 device.
I have a label that increments by +/- Buttons, but i want to give option for user to insert his number to this label.
How can i do it with long press recogniser?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to use a UITextView if you want it to be editable.

Comment: i tried it, i have a keyboard that is not disappear after enter a number.

Comment: Do you want the keyboard to be dismissed when you tap outside the text view?

Comment: After i press a done on keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and a `UITextView`.

Add a `UILongPressGstureRecognizer` property to your view controller:

```
@property UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer;
```

You need to declare that your view controller conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` and `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocols:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.textView.editable = NO;
self.textView.delegate = self;
self.gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textViewLongPressed:)];
self.gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.textView addGestureRecognizer:self.gr];
```

This is the method that will be called when you long press the text view:

```
-(void) textViewLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    self.textView.editable = YES;
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Implement this method from the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (self.gestureRecognizer == gestureRecognizer){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

When you finish editing the text view

```
-(void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.textView.editable = NO;
}
```

To dismiss the keyboard when you press return:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        [textView resignFirstResponder]; // or [textView endEditing:YES]

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: 1.the keyboard is not dissapear
2.I have a warning: Assigning to 'id<UITextViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'GoalsSetUpViewController *const __strong'

Comment: The keyboard can be dismissed  if i not entered number or press another button on view?

Comment: if i long press second time i the keyboard is not appears

Comment: No, but if you call `resignFirstResponder` on the text view when the button is pressed, it will be dismissed.

Comment: Thanks, and why there is no keyboard on second press?

Comment: @user3428151 I needed to implement a method from the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol. It works now - see my updated answer

Comment: It is still do not appear

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to include `self.gestureRecognizer.delegate = self` in `viewDidload`.It should work now.

Comment: May be you what can be done if my textview is hidden by the keyboard?

Comment: You can move your view up. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears