# date changing when it is extracted from an array

Tags: ios

i m storing the dates in an array using this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
today = [NSDate date];
[checkinArray addObject:today];
```

in the array it is storing as 
    checkinArray
        [0] = 2014-05-22 11:21:09 IST

and when i'm extracting the date from the array through this statement

```
NSString *dummystr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[checkinArray lastObject]];
```

the date has been changing to another timezone

i.e., 2014-05-22 05:51:09 +0000

thanks in advance and anyhelp is appreciable.

Comment: How do you imagine your calendar? Could a UICollectionView be what you're looking for? Did you look on some GitHub projects or CocoaControls for already done things?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
i've seen in Github, but i haven't found any help according to my requirement. the calendar has to look simple like dates has to be displayed in a row.

Comment: How do you imagine your calendar looks like? Any "screenshot"/drawing?

Comment: i m trying to upload the screeenshot. but an error is occuring that i have to be 10 reputation to upload a picture. help needed here also.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/esGDy.png

Comment: here i upload the screenshot of how my view has to look like.
here i upload the screenshot when i select the month, a pickerview of months has to appear and the dates should display in a row

Comment: @sreekanthk - in your code can you explain me where you suing  `dateformat` ??