# How to reposition UITextField up without a Scroll View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift

I have the following issue:

I have a parent view. Inside this is a scroll view with different text fields and labels. When a text field is being edited, I reposition the text field to the top of the screen so that the keyboard does not hide the textfields.

One of the text fields has a table view below it which is used a dropdown. when text is entered, it shows various results dynamically. This table view is also added to the scrollview. This is not a recommended and also does not work. So how can I achieve this whitout using scrollview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears

Comment: :) thanks. I posted this before I your suggestion, trying to find better design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hackerinheels has mentioned above, use this method to reposition elements, so that the keyboard does not obstruct your text fields.

Avoid using scrollview for repositioning, as adding tableview inside scrollview is problematic.

[Xcode/iOS5: Move UIView up, when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952762/xcode-ios5-move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears)